# Dont know how to turn on Wireless

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

I have a Toshiba Satellite Windows 7 (64) without its Factory Hard Drive. Had to replace it with a new one so all the **Toshiba Drivers used for the FN Keys are gone so the one key that turns it on no longer works.**

Here my problem, I don't know how to turn it on with out that key or what Toshiba Drivers to install to get that key to work again. The Wireless Driver/Device is installed and I cant even enable it in the "Windows Mobility Center" for some odd reason.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can you see the wireless interface in your list of network connections? Double check that you haven't turned off the wireless antenna by hitting a physical toggle on one of the sides of the laptop. Sometimes they are quite easy to over look and miss.

Comment: There is no side buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Like most manufacturers, if you go to their website and then to support, you will be asked to put in your model and or serial number.  Then you select Drivers and you will be taken to a site with the drivers for that specific system.  While you are there, pickup a copy of the manual for your computer as well.